# "list index out of range" warnings on python exec()

Tags: python, ide

I am debugging a python script in Thonny using Python 3 (3.5.3). I am running this on a Raspberry Pi ZeroW with Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59+ #1047. I am remotely connected via realVNC over Wi-Fi.

The Python script has some initialization code that sets some variables to default values. The script runs as desired; no errors.

I am adding the ability to read a set of configuration parameters from a file to initialize the variables.

```
config = {}
config_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
config_file = config_dir + "/temps.conf"
with open(config_file, "r") as fh:
    exec(fh.read()+"\n", config)
    fh.close()
```

Simply beginning to debug the script (i.e., not a single line of code interpreted, just ctrl+F5) causes a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/ast_utils.py", line 178, in _mark_text_ranges_rec
    tokens = _mark_end_and_return_child_tokens(node, tokens, prelim_end_lineno, prelim_end_col_offset)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/ast_utils.py", line 263, in _mark_end_and_return_child_tokens
    _strip_trailing_junk_from_expressions(tokens)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/shared/thonny/ast_utils.py", line 202, in _strip_trailing_junk_from_expressions
    while (tokens[-1].type not in (token.RBRACE, token.RPAR, token.RSQB,
"IndexError: list index out of range"
```

By commenting out the new block of code and uncommenting one statement at a time, I have narrowed down the statement causing the error to the "exec(...)" line. Again, the error occurs prior to any statements running. Although the error happens, Thonny allows me to continue executing the script. If I step through the program, I was expecting the exec statement to fail. In fact, the code executes fine. The configuration file is read and loaded into my config array. I can then retrieve the parameters throughout the rest of my Python script.

Therefore, it appears that this traceback is more of a warning rather than a critical error. I could ignore it, but I expect this is trying to tell me something - where there's smoke, there's likely a smoldering fire. I'd like to understand what is causing the issue so that I can eliminate it.

Thank you for your insights!

UPDATE - contents of the temps.conf file

```
# Configuration for temperature logging scripts.
#
# Create a copy of this file, adjust it to suit your needs, and save the copy as
# `temps.conf` in the same directory.

#
# Local Temperature sensor settings.
#

# Calibration for local temperature sensor, in degrees F (e.g. 3 -2, -1.24).
# Average variance in temperature readings between Nest thermostat and Pimoroni enviroPhat
local_temp_offset = 8.95

# Temperature difference trigger threshold, in degrees F.
temp_threshold = 2

# Amount of time to wait before checking temperature after adjustment, in seconds.
wait_to_temp = 300

# Looping cycle delay between local temperature readings when just monitoring temperature, in seconds.
local_temp_read_delay = 30

# Open Weather Maps API Key
owm_api_key = 'OWN_API_KEY'

# Nest - Cannot set target temperatures closer than 3.0 degrees F 
nest_heat_cool_spread = 3

# Nest Developers Cloud API parameters.
nest_client_id = 'NEST_CLIENT_ID'
nest_client_secret = 'NEST_CLIENT_SECRET'
nest_access_token_cache_file = '/home/pi/.config/nest/token_cache'
```

Mike

Comment: For one thing, `exec`ing a config file is a bad idea, but that aside, please [edit] in the contents of your `"/temps.conf"` file.

Comment: @Norrius I added the configuration file contents as requested. As I am very much a novice, I just found an example of that used execfile() and updated it for Python 3. I definitely don't know better ;-) Rather than use exec() for this purpose, could you direct me to the proper method (with sample code if possible)? Thanks.

Comment: Your code is fine (`.close()` is not needed when you use `with open()` though), that error looks like a bug in your IDE's debugger / AST analyser.

Comment: @Norrius Thonny IDE bug - that's the conclusion I reached as well. I ran the code from a terminal window and it did not raise any errors. I just wanted to confirm. Thanks! P.S. I'll clean up the .close() Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in Thonny. I created an issue: https://bitbucket.org/plas/thonny/issues/396/exec-causes-range-marker-to-crash